# Select and play a video in Access using a Subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, windows-media-player

I am working on a DB that links users to training videos.

The primary Form "2_CCC" has the Windows media player plugin. That works.

The Subform has all the video files.

The issue is that I can't pass the address from the Subform to the media player. The address is stored in a TextBox called "Video."

```vb
Public Sub PlaybButton_Click()

Dim videoaddress As String

videoaddress = Forms![2_CCC]![2_CCC_Subform].Form![Video]

Forms![2_CCC]!WMP.URL = videoaddress 

End Sub
```

I get

> Automation error.

I redid the code:

```vb
Public Sub PlaybButton_Click()

Forms![2_CCC]!WMP.URL = Forms![2_CCC]![2_CCC_Subform].Form![Video]

End Sub
```

If I put the file path directly in the code, it works.

I thought it might be an issue with not passing into the primary Form.

I added a TextBox to the primary form called "VideoSelect"

```vb
Public Sub PlaybButton_Click()

Dim videoaddress As String

videoaddress = Forms![2_CCC]![2_CCC_Subform].Form![Video]

Forms![2_CCC]!WMP.URL = videoaddress 

End Sub
```

I get a new error

> You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property.

I did a MsgBox to see what VideoSelect displays, and it is showing the correct file address.

Comment: Referencing a textbox works for me and I wouldn't bother with variable. `Me.WMP.URL = Me.[2_CCC_Subform].Form.[Video]`.

Comment: Crap. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Are you triggering the video from the primary form or the sub?

Comment: From the main form. You? If you want to run from subform `Me.Parent.WMP.URL = Me.Video`.

Comment: I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. 

I created a new form linked to the table with all of the videos. I made a textbox that displays the location. 

So I just set did "me.wmp.url = me.location" and that failed. I Then I just copied the address into the code: "me.wmp.url = "E:\Videos\Howtocreatevideo.mp4" Which works. I'm at a total loss for what I'm missing.

Comment: Please check the control name of the subform embedding 2_CCC_Subform.   Is it 2_CCC_Subform or Subform1?

Comment: Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I copied your code exactly as it is, and it works without any problems

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure it's something with my computer. I've tried this in like a dozen different ways and I keep getting the "invalid reference" error. 

Thank you all for looking it over. Sorry for the goose chase! 

Now I need to figure out another way to play videos...

Comment: I got it to work!!!!!!!!!!! This issue was with the quotations. If I bring it over without the quotes, it works! No idea why, but whatever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that the quotation marks from the file pathway were causing an issue with the WMP player.

So I just added a step to remove those.

The code is now quite simple and works 100% of the time.

```
Forms![2_CCC}!WMP.URL = Replace(Forms![2_CCC]![2_CCC_Subform].Form![Video],"""","")
```